# a simple str_replace of comma but not working on string that looks like JSON result

Tags: str-replace

I just want to do a simple str_replace to remove a comma from a template of  WordPress Visual Composer but it is not working. Most probably it is due to JSON string which I am not familiar with.

The original code :

```
$content = '{{ post_data:' . esc_attr( $data_source ) . ' }}';
$output .= 'someotherhtmlstuff'. $content;
echo $output;
```

$content is actually a date and it display on the browser as "July 25, 2015".

What I did :

```
$content = '{{ post_data:' . esc_attr( $data_source ) . ' }}';
$content = str_replace(',', '', $content);
$output .= 'someotherhtmlstuff'. $content;
echo $output;
```

It never finds the comma and always return as "July 25, 2015".

If I hardcode the content to :

```
$content = 'July 25, 2015';
$content = str_replace(',', '', $content);
$output .= 'someotherhtmlstuff'. $content;
echo $output;
```

The result is correct "July 25 2015".

What is this actually?

```
$content = '{{ post_data:' . esc_attr( $data_source ) . ' }}';
```

Why doesn't echo returns "{{ post_data: post_date }}" but as the string "July 25, 2015" which couldn't be read as a string in str_replace?

Comment: [esc_attr](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr): Encodes the <, >, &, " and ' (less than, greater than, ampersand, double quote and single quote) characters. Will never double encode entities.

Comment: Just before you do `str_replace`, could you do `print_r($content);` and add  the output to your question?

Comment: I have tried these but no result 

$myJSONString = json_encode($content);
echo "myJSONString : " . $myJSONString ."<br>";
$content = str_replace(',', '', $myJSONString);


This returns "July 25, 2015"  (with the double quotes)

$myArray = json_decode($content );
print "myArray : " . $myArray ."<br>";
$content = str_replace(',', '', $myArray );

This returns empty

FYI, the Visual Composer is loading this script as ajax showing all the news articles.

Comment: @zedfoxus print_r($content) shows the same thing : July 25, 2015

Comment: var_dump(json_decode($content, true));
is showing NULL, so it isn't an array?

Comment: ok.. var_dump($content) is returning this:  string(25) "July 25, 2015" 
what is it? how to I turn it into normal string to use in str_replace?

Comment: Could you let me know the output of `$content = '{{ post_data:' . esc_attr( $data_source ) . ' }}'; echo base64_encode($content);`?

Comment: `echo base64_encode($content); result is e3sgcG9zdF9kYXRhOnBvc3RfZGF0ZSB9fQ== `

Comment: That output just results in `{{ post_data:post_date }}`. I imagine that `post_date` is enumerated back to some data. Just before `echo $output;` type `echo str_replace(',', '', $output);` What's the result of that?

Comment: The result is the same. the comma is not replaced.

Comment: `$content = '{{ post_data:' . esc_attr( $data_source ) . ' }}';
echo base64_encode($content);
var_dump($content);`

Why is both outputs different from each other?

Comment: echo is printing base 64 encoding of $content. var_dump is printing unencoded $content. That's why they are different. As to why the `,` doesnt get replaced, I don't know.

Comment: Please contact visual composer support by opening support ticket in support.wpbakery.com, as for your question I can try to help but I need all code what you are using and trying to get. Explain all details what you expect to get, send me email at: pavel@wpbakery.com

Comment: I have a similir problem with `{{ post_data:ID }}`. I want to use it with `wp_get_post_tags($id)`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing an str_replace on {{ post_data:postdate }} as in

```
$content = str_replace(',', '', '{{ post_data:postdate }}');
```

Which has no comma, it's a template tag that is replaced later on in the rendering process.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that applying replacement of template tag will not provide any good result.
You should use filter that actually process tag replacement on proper value, for Post Grid it will be:

```
add_filter( 'vc_gitem_template_attribute_post_date', function ( $value, $data ) {
    return str_replace(',', '', $value);    
}, 20, 2 );
```